# Get POST'ed data from HTML page to Node.Js / Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node.js / express and I have a question. I'm searching this for hours.

I'm trying to make an admin panel for my basic blog and I need to POST:

`title` & `content` from input in HTML
to my `panel.js`

Here is what I tried:

Post data from HTML page, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#but').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     var title = document.getElementById('title');
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/panel/save",
          data: title.value,
          dataType: "json"
    });


    });
  });
```

And `panel.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();


router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('panel_html');

});

/* mysql things */

router.get('/save/', function(req, res) {
   var t = req.params.title;
    console.log("title :"+t);
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

Error report:

```
14 Aug 20:49:33 - [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
14 Aug 20:49:33 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
GET /panel/ 304 11ms
GET /lib/semantic/build/packaged/javascript/semantic.js 304 4ms
GET /lib/semantic/build/packaged/css/semantic.css 304 5ms
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 7ms
GET /lib/semantic/build/packaged/fonts/icons.svg 304 1ms
GET /lib/semantic/build/packaged/fonts/icons.woff 304 0ms
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "...site/views"
    at Function.app.render (...site/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:492:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (...site/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:802:7)
    at Layer.module.exports [as handle] (...site/app.js:74:9)
    at trim_prefix (...site/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:235:17)
    at ...site/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:208:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (...site/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:269:12)
    at IncomingMessage.next (...site/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:199:19)
    at fn (...site/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:797:25)
    at Function.app.render (...site/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:494:14)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (...site/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:802:7)
POST /panel/save 500 11ms - 1.13kb
```

Google Chrome Console :

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/panel/save 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Since you have a `POST` request, you should use `route.post('/save')...`. And you should also render some other view inside your callback, in order to show the user the response data (success or error).

Comment: Thanks, I've learned it now and I'm trying to figure out other things.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you name your `title` variable when you pass it into your ajax call by placing it in an object literal:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/panel/save",
  data: { title: title.value },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Next, change your `router.get` to `router.post` so it can accept the route. Next, you should be accessing your postdata through `req.body`. Just make sure you're `use`ing express's [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) somewhere in your app prior to this route declaration.

```
router.post('/save/', function(req, res) {
   var t = req.body.title;
    console.log("title :"+t);
});
```

Comment: First, thank you. I added the error report to question. I'm seeing `POST` method is getting successfully by `panel.js` but it's not showing in console and there is an error I'm getting for hours. Can you check?